# Recuperar elemento DOM de uma coluna

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Tenho um evento no Jquery que caputura as informações da uma linha da tabela (estou usando o DataTables Jquery).

```
var linha = $(this).parents('tr')[0].innerHTML;
```

O valor retornado é esse:

```
<td class="text-center sorting_1">118587</td>                                   
<td class="font-w600">113326</td>                                 
<td class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">JOÃO DA SIILVA(<b>68</b>)</td>                                   
<td class="text-center">
    <button id="btnIncluiVisitante" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i><label for=""></label>                                       
    </button>
    <button id="btnRemoveVisitante" class="btn btn-primary">                                            
        <i class="fa fa-user-times"></i>
        <label id="qtdeVisitantes">1</label>
    </button>                                     
</td>
```

Como eu faço para pegar o valor `1` que está na tag `<i>` com `id="qtdeVisitantes"`?

Comment: **Uma dica**: Evite ficar misturando as sintaxes do Vanilla com jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer pegar do primeiro objeto seria:

```
$(linha).find("#qtdVisitantes").text();
```

Se #qtdVisitantes for único (como deveria ser) basta esse código:

```
$("#qtdeVisitantes").text();
```

Uma outra sintaxe para pegar direto o valor (imagino que ao clique do botão btnRemoveVisitante) seria:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("#qtdVisitantes").text();
```

OBS: Imagino que existam muitos elementos com a mesma id #qtdVisitantes, nesse caso não é adequado, pois ID's devem ser únicos, se for possível troque por classe.

Comment: Obrigado João, é isso mesmo. O fato de ter vários id #qtdVisitantes já havia tratado anteriormente. 
Meu erro está em não utilizar a variável "linha" como variável do Jquery. Agora coloquei a variável $(linha) e consigo utilizar o método find().

Comment: Sim, quando colocamos no seletor jquery $() uma string contendo html ele automaticamente transforma num objeto jquery, permitindo utilizar todas as funções do mesmo.